# How to configure yocto to use the latest git commit?

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I am a very lazy person. While working on a HW/SW project the software changes permanently. In this development stage, changing the commit/reversion-tags in the recipes is very nasty.
I want Yocto to fetch the latest git commit. Is this possible/How to do this?
My example recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "my test"
SECTION = "test"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit cmake
SRCREV = "f9bdbd6c631f07e427c010086c7c26a95eb2924e"

SRC_URI = "gitsm://myGit/mytest;protocol=http;branch=develop"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/"
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sure, set `SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"`.

Furthermore, [you need to reference SRCPV](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/packages.html#automatically-incrementing-a-package-version-number) in PV in order to automatically update the version whenever the revision of the source code changes. Here is an example:

```
 PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
```

Then it'll build the latest revision each time.

Comment: As it is, bitbake will not rebuild the package if the repo is updated. You must add *PV = "0.1+git${SRCPV}"* as well to enable this. https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#automatically-incrementing-a-binary-package-revision-number

Comment: @JetskiS-type *"bitbake will not rebuild the package if the repo is updated. You must add PV = "0.1+git${SRCPV}" as well to enable this*" - this is false. The fetcher will re-fetch a branch HEAD every time `AUTOREV` is parsed. `PV` is only for output package name version number. *"in order to automatically update the version"* - read the spec again carefully :)

Comment: @bloody, late, but.. so you do think that bitbake will rebuild the package if the repo is updated without setting PV? 8 people agree with me (as of time of writing). Did you try it out before writing your comment?

Comment: @JetskiS-type Since Yocto ZEUS release yes, it does with `SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"`, I have tried it. Btw. also quite old already (nowadays we use HARDKNOTT). "People" use old stuff apparently.

Comment: @bloody ah, good to know then. I can't find it in the release notes for Zeus. I ran into that problem in an older version for sure, but already updated all the recipes accordingly before updating the Yocto version, so I wasn't in a position to notice (and I don't actively use it now).